# Elastic search multi_match with field boost

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a `title` and `description` fields. I want to find both `apple` and `banana` in either of fields. But `title` has greater score, i.e. documents with `apple` and `banana` in title should have greater score than documents with the same terms in `description`.

If both terms in both fields then they should have even greater score (but this is optional if this is hard to do).

My attempt:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "apple banana",
      "type":       "best_fields",
      "fields":     [ "title^2", "description" ],
      "operator":   "and" 
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work as expected.
Also, is there any difference between `title^2` and `title^3`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document having `apple banana` in the `title` field has a higher score as compared to the document having `apple banana` in `description` field

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "title":"apple banana",
    "description":"abc"
}
{
    "title":"abc",
    "description":"apple banana"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "apple banana",
      "type":       "best_fields",
      "fields":     [ "title^2", "description" ],
      "operator":   "and" 
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66890080",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 2.589756,
        "_source": {
          "title": "apple banana",
          "description": "abc"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66890080",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.294878,
        "_source": {
          "title": "abc",
          "description": "apple banana"
        }
      }
    ]
```

---

> Also, is there any difference between title^2 and title^3

Individual fields can be boosted with `^`. In `title^2` the score of `title` field will be multiplied by 2 and in `title^3` the score will be multiplied by 3